# How to put three images in a row

Tags: graphics, wide-image

I use Overleaf when writing my thesis.

I want to put three images in a row, but I can't do it.

I'm using this code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img/grafo1.png} 
       \caption{Grafo non orientato}
       \label{fig:subim1}
   \end{subfigure}
   
   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img/grafo2.png}
       \caption{Grafo orientato}
       \label{fig:subim2}
   \end{subfigure}

   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img/grafo3.png}
       \caption{Grafo orientato}
       \label{fig:subim3}
   \end{subfigure}

   \caption{Esempi di grafi}
   \label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
```

But the result is this:

[image]

All the 3 images have a size of 400x400.

How can I solve ? Thanks ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The total width of your subfigures is `0.4*3` = `1.2\textwidth`, so it's not surprising that it won't fit on a line. So first change those values to something that adds up to 1, and make the images smaller as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your opinion, which could be the correct dimension to do this ? I'm a beginner of latex. I tried with 0.3, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alan Munn pointed in his comment, your subimage environments are to wide that can be fit in one row. Try do the the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete demo option
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] % <---
   \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/grafo1.png}
       \caption{Grafo non orientato}
       \label{fig:subim1}
   \end{subfigure}
\hfill % <--- 
   \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/grafo2.png}
       \caption{Grafo orientato}
       \label{fig:subim2}
   \end{subfigure}
\hfill % <---
   \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/grafo3.png}
       \caption{Grafo orientato}
       \label{fig:subim3}
   \end{subfigure}

   \caption{Esempi di grafi}
   \label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you see, in above MWE are removed empty lines between images (which force that next image go to the next row), reduced size of `subfigures` so that their sum is less than 1 and defined width of images to be equal to width of `subfugure`s.

PLease, always provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem (As I doo in above suggested solution).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It works perfectly. 
I'm really a beginner with Latex and I'm trying to fully understand it. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Lx2pwn, you are welcome! Happy TeXing, and Happy New Year of course!